# How to use Python Decorator to change only one part of function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dry, python-decorators

I am practically repeating the same code with only one minor change in each function, but an essential change.

I have about 4 functions that look similar to this:

```
def list_expenses(self):
    explist = [(key,item.amount) for key, item in self.expensedict.iteritems()] #create a list from the dictionary, making a tuple of dictkey and object values
    sortedlist = reversed(sorted(explist, key = lambda (k,a): (a))) #sort the list based on the value of the amount in the tuples of sorted list. Reverse to get high to low
    for ka in sortedlist:
          k, a = ka
          print k , a

def list_income(self):
    inclist = [(key,item.amount) for key, item in self.incomedict.iteritems()] #create a list from the dictionary, making a tuple of dictkey and object values
    sortedlist = reversed(sorted(inclist, key = lambda (k,a): (a))) #sort the list based on the value of the amount in the tuples of sorted list. Reverse to get high to low
    for ka in sortedlist:
        k, a = ka
        print k , a
```

I believe this is what they refer to as violating "DRY", however I don't have any idea how I can change this to be more DRYlike, as I have two seperate dictionaries(expensedict and incomedict) that I need to work with.

I did some google searching and found something called decorators, and I have a very basic understanding of how they work, but no clue how I would apply it to this.

**So my request/question:**

1. Is this a candidate for a decorator, and if a decorator is
   necessary, could I get  hint as to what the decorator should do?
2. Pseudocode is fine. I don't mind struggling. I just need something
   to start with.

Comment: Konstantin's answer is the way to go. I just want to add that this kind of processing can be written in a much more compact way, e.g., `for k, i in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda t: t[1].amount): print k, i.amount`

Comment: With this, I can  completely cut out the list comprehension it seems. I know this may seem stupid, but could you tell me how the lambda:t  t[1] works?  How does the lambda become  list?

Comment: Nvm, just realized sorted of iterkeys returns a tuple and tuples can be indexed! You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think about using a separate function (as a private method) for list processing? For example, you may do the following:

```
def __list_processing(self, list): 
    #do the generic processing of your lists

def list_expenses(self):
    #invoke __list_processing with self.expensedict as a parameter

def list_income(self):
    #invoke __list_processing with self.incomedict as a parameter
```

It looks better since all the complicated processing is in a single place, `list_expenses` and `list_income` etc are the corresponding wrapper functions.

Comment: This does sound very concise, and seems to be the simplest way to cut down on code. Being a relativelg new Python programmer, I guess I just jumped to the conclusion that it had to be complex.